# Instantiating data access objects in ASP .NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have to develop a `WEB API` for my current project. My database is `POSTGRESQL` and I am not using `Entity Framework`. I am having my own data access layer. Now within the each (`GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc) method of each controller I want to access the database. Now my question is that what is the correct approach to instantiate the data access layer object. Following two are the approaches :-

1. Instantiate it in every method of each controller and destroy it there after completing the work. But I think it will be a costly affair to instantiate and destroy object every time.
2. Instantiate it globally one time and access it from each method of each controller.

What is the correct approach to do it?

I will be very thankful.

Comment: I think you need to show us at least some code from the *data access layer object*. If you create/abandon it it in every method, you (most likely) don't have to deal with thread synchronization issues. That may be the case if you try in create and reuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this question depends very much on how you have implemented your data access layer. Having said that, it is certainly possible to give you some general pointers which may help you out. Creating individual objects in C# is generally not a particularly expensive operation, rather it is the resources attached to those objects which tend to be expensive. As the postgresql C# provider supports connection pooling (I assume you are using [the npgsql driver?](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html)), a new connection to the database will not be created each time you instantiate one of your data access objects, but instead the connections will be held in a pool and allocated as required by your code. So, in order to avoid complexity and state-handling, the simplest approach would probably be to create a new object in each method of your controller.

Alternatively you could add your data access object as a private field to your controller and instantiate it in the constructor of your controller assuming that all of your controller methods require your data access layer. This might help to avoid some code repetition and the lifetime of the object will be very similar in both cases, i.e. one object per request.